# M1 Mac Trying to npm run start but unable to fetch DynamoDB tables from aws. ERROR failed to setConfig. Failed to read aws region

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, apple-m1, aws-config

Hi I am working on a node uplift project but fetching DynamoDB tables from M1 Mac is challenging. So far I am getting these error messages as follows

```
aupm:DynamoInit Failed to set config +0ms
aupm:DynamoInit Error: Failed to read the AWS region from config
aupm:DynamoInit     at Object.setConfig (/Users/----/Documents/CMS/---    -/src/db/DataLayer.js:202:29)
```

.aws/config file does have the region but still failing.

Can you someone help me understand what is wrong and how can I fix it?
I am a novice.

Comment: Can you please add more details so that readers can reproduce your problem? How exactly are you accessing DynamoDB?

Comment: Yes please. I will get some more info from debug. Get back to you soon.